# Why Runtime exception on calling add for a fixed size list?

Tags: java

Below is my list defination.

```
static List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(112, 323, 368, 369, 378);
```

The list is having fixed size as 5.

On calling a add like this

```
list.add(200);
```

Should not  this be a compile time error ? Rather it threw below exception 
at runtime

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We knew that `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` of fixed size backed by an `array` of fixed length.

Now the compiler doesn't know the length of the array at compile time. unless you run the program, you don't know the length at runtime.

In short, *you can't modify an array at compile time* :)

Comment: call to asList() itself can suggest that add/remove not permitted. So compiler can throw exception . isn't it?

Comment: And the compiler also doesn't know that the array is "fixed size". It's an implementation detail known only to the class.

Comment: @AbhishekSaxena Compiler cannot magically guess (that you are going to add few things to it) and throw exceptions. It exactly throws exceptions when you are trying/doing abnormal things..

Answer (score 3):

From Java DOCs

```
Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.
This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements:

     List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");

Parameters:
a - the array by which the list will be backed
Returns:
a list view of the specified array
```

Since this is fixed size so you cant modify add elements to this list.

Comment: OP knows the it's not supported. Question is, `why the compiler don't know`

Answer (score 2):

This List implementation you receive from Arrays.asList is a special view on the array - you can't change it's size.

Comment: Agreed for instance for given code 5 is the list size. I know the size cannot be changed. My question is why runtime and not compile time exception ?I wish to understand this

Comment: OP knows the it's not supported. Question is, why the compiler don't know